# PDFLib.Objects library giving encoding issues on the pdf generated

Tags: .net, encoding, character, ascii

While using PDFLib.Objects library to generate templates could observe some character encoding issues .

## Example :Boétie is getting converted to BoÃ©️tie.

Please be informed the application is in .net.
Could anyone  please help acheiving it ?

Expecting Boétie with special character being present but it’s getting converted into ascii.

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in PowerShell variant of `.NET`*): `[System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding( 1252).GetString( [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding( 'UTF-8').GetBytes( 'Boétie'))` returns `BoÃ©tie`…

Comment: Thanks for the response .Can we avoid the conversion using same pdf lib? We’re in need of printing the actual word(Boétie) with out any conversion .